# Windows 10: Shift+Tab not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, vnc, tightvnc

On a Windows 10 box, I found that I can't send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to (at least some) applications, such as Notepad++.

I am using that machine remotely via a VNC session (Remmina client under Xubuntu, the Windows machine is running TightVNC server) and my original thought was that the shortcut gets processed by the VNC client or the local OS, but testing the same with a remote Xubuntu machine *does* send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through; e.g. I could unindent a line in Mousepad which is Xubuntu's default text editor.

Is there a Windows 10 setting or shortcut causing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to be directed away from Notepad++?

Any information on how I could debug this issue would also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to send shitf+tab on a webpage (for instance this page) and see if it jumps through the links?

Comment: Another question: What about other shortcuts such as shift+ctl+tab, alt+tab, etc. Are they working?

Comment: What about Backspace, or Shift-Backspace?

Comment: @Woeitg Shift+Tab on webpages doesn't work either. Normal Tab does advance through the page's links/fields. What is Shift+Ctrl+Tab supposed to do? It doesn't seem to do anything in either Firefox nor in Notepad++ on the remote Win10 box.

Comment: @Didier Both Shift+Backspace and Backspace alone are working as expected (they delete the character before the caret) in NP++ on my remote Win10 box.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+Tab cycles through Notepad++ tabs

Comment: @Woeitg Ah, yes, of course... I just hadn't had more than 1 tab open. Now with 3 open, Ctrl+Tab cycles through them (forward), but Shift+Ctrl+Tab doesn't seem to get through.

Comment: I suspect all shortcuts with "shift" in it does not work. You may try yourself all different shortcuts and see if it is true: http://code2care.org/pages/97-notpad-plus-plus-keyboard-shortcuts-key-list/

Comment: @Woeitg Good idea. But it's not true: I can at least Ctrl+Shift+F (find in files), Shift+F3 (find previous), Ctrl+Shift+U (uppercase selection), Shift+F2 (goto previous bookmark), Ctrl+Shift+S (save as) and Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down (move current line up/down)

Comment: So to conclude, what are the shortcuts that are not working? only Shift + Tab?

Comment: you may also try to use OSK to simulate shift +tab and see if it works

Comment: @Woeitg so far I have only noticed Shift+Tab missing. Using an OSK on the Win10 box, it works. Using the OSK of the local machine only works for local apps, the Win10 box doesn't appear to register it.

Comment: Have you tried with the function keys (F1 to F12), just in case? I doubt it'll do any good, but who know.

Comment: Try to press the key in Remmina Preferences > Keyboard tab > Grab keyboard, just before the shift+tab. See also if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085004/963426) is relevant.

Comment: @Didier I now tested all combinations Shift+F1 to Shift+F12 (temporariloy re-mapped the ones I hadn't tested to "New File"), all are working.

Comment: @harrymc I tested with both "Grab keyboard" option on and off, same result. I just tried the `xmodmap` part of the linked answer and it is working now, but I'd like to know what this change does and why this is necessary. If you could explain what the problem is with the default keyboard mapping and how the modification fixes it, I'd be more than happy to accept an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below fixed the problem for the user.
The problem is that basically the combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
is not unique and may be mistaken when transmitted to the server.
This problem may occur when using VNC between non-Linux and Linux computers.

This same problem is evoked in the post
[using Alt-Gr from a Windows VNC client to vino](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353304).
Although dating from 2007, the
[answer by  Dan Winship](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353304#c21)
still applies:

> the problem is that the server side (the machine running vino)
>   considers the Tab key to have two different keysyms on it (Tab and
>   ISO_Left_Tab respectively), whereas the client side considers it to
>   only have one keysym on it, and so expects Shift+Tab to be treated the
>   same way as Shift+Up Arrow.
>
> (I assume the client is a non-Linux box?)
>
> I don't think there's a "clean" fix for this; the client and server
>   are both behaving reasonably, this is just one of those warts in the
>   protocol. The only way to fix it would be to special-case the Tab key
>   in the code. If you want to suggest doing that, you should probably
>   file a new bug (and refer to the comments in this one).
>
> You can work around the bug by running
>
> `xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Tab'`
>
> (on the vino box). This doesn't seem to interfere with ordinary gtk
>   operation, so it's probably safe to do this all the time. (Eg, putting
>   `'keycode 23 = Tab'` into `~/.xmodmap` or `~/.Xmodmap` or something might
>   cause it to automatically be evaluated, depending on your distro)

In the more recent post
[Shift + special key does not work using real vnc viewer in windows to access ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084884/shift-special-key-does-not-work-using-real-vnc-viewer-in-windows-to-access-ubu)
where the same method was used to fix the problem:

> Run in Ubuntu terminal: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Tab'`
>
> EDIT: to make the fix permanent run `sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and change the line
>
> > `key  <TAB> {    [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };`
>
> to
>
> > `key  <TAB> {    [ Tab                   ]   };`
>
> After that reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While the `xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Tab'` command seems to have worked, trying to make it permanent via editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` didn't: I got the [no keyboard is found problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/458615/181442) at the login screen. Note that I have only tried to comment the original line with `//` and add the new `key` line, so syntax errors *could* be an issue there... I'll need to backup the file and edit the line in-place to see if this will work. Note to self: I had to fix the login via [GRUB recovery](https://askubuntu.com/a/150377/181442).

Comment: It works without the comment line, just delete the part `,  ISO_Left_Tab` from the `key  <TAB>` line.